# Windows 8 store app cannot reach local server

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, lan

I am developing a line of business app (so store rules do not apply for me) which requires to reach a http server in local network.

I've checked Private Networks (Client & Server), and create make a request from the code (something like http:// XX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX/abc)
While debugging in Visual Studio everything works fine as expected, but the request is blocked (even if firewall is off) when I published the app and used it in another computer.

I can still reach the server using both Metro & Desktop IE. Only user written apps seem to have problem.

Answer (score 0):

you might need to add these lines into the appmanifest

```
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT" />
```

Comment: those capabilities are for windows phone 8, not valid for windows 8 store applications